# System.out.println() calls being ignored as well as an element not being added into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader, println

I'm currently working on a program to read in info from a text file and output it on a spreadsheet using Apache's POI.

Let me show you what I have

```
    ExcelFile ef = new ExcelFile(file, "the destination");
```

The constructor for the ExcelFileObject:

```
    public ExcelFile(File file, String fp){
    System.out.println("Entered ExcelFile constructor");
    util = new ExcelUtilities();
    this.filepath = fp;
    this.data = util.readFromFile(file);
}
```

And then the readFromFile method:

```
public ArrayList<InputData> readFromFile(File file){
    System.out.println("Entered readFromFile in ExcelUtilities");
    ArrayList<InputData> data = new ArrayList<InputData>();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.length() > 0){
                System.out.println(line);
                int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                System.out.println(x);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                System.out.println(y);
                data.add(new InputData(line, x, y)); //Not adding the first thing read in for some odd reason.
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return data;
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem I ran into was that the first object from the .txt file formatted correctly was not being added to the ArrayList data. When I ran in the debugger (using Eclipse), I noticed that it was reading in the first line, x, and y values but never actually storing the object in `data`.

Then I ran into an even stranger problem. I added the System.out.println() statements as another level of verification that the data from the file was being read in properly, and they weren't even being printed onto the console! I tried running another project that contained println()'s and they worked fine.

So, I guess the main question is why isn't the first entree from the file being added the ArrayList? Followed by why aren't the println() calls being displayed on Eclipse's console?

The selected box in the output is where "Hello" should be placed.

[image: Sample Input]

[image: Output]

Comment: please post the complete output of your program.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle okay, added pictures for sample input and corresponding output. There's more to it but the rest is definitely working fine.

Comment: What do you see in your console?

Comment: Show the `InputData` class and how you're outputting it.

Comment: Nothing. Before I added the println()'s for testing, there was nothing in the console. But, what confuses me is now that I've added them, there's still nothing showing up.

Comment: @shmosel InputData only contains a String and two ints as well as a toString method that I never ended up actually using.